# How can I convert cells containing than 15 digit number limitation to the real value

Tags: vba, excel, office365

I didn't realise there is a limit on the maximum number allowed in all versions of Excel (15 digits long max).

I've made an error by manually entering loads of values only to discover that I lose the accuracy after the first 15 digits which are replaced by zeroes in affect. It was nearly a 3 hour piece of work which it looks like I will have to repeat unless anyone know a way to help me.

Since then I've saved and exited my spreadsheet. Later on a customer came back to me to say that that the numbers I gave them are inaccurate as they only only go up to 15 digits for accuracy.

I then researched this on the net to find that I should have formatted the column as Text before copying in the number that is more than 15 characters.

Does anyone know if there is any way to get the numbers back or is will I have generate my spreadsheet all over again?

Comment: What does your question have to do with VBA or Excel VBA?

Comment: There is no way to get back truncated fractuonal part.

Comment: Ken - as you'll know, a lot of things can be fixed using VBA but not through the normal Excel functions so that was why I queried it with the VBA experts as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the numbers back. You will have to generate your spreadsheet again.

Comment: To encapsulate this for you @MasterSQL, look at an individual cell where you've entered, say, a 17 digit number. The actual number shown in Excel in the formula bar is immediately changed to a 15 digit number * 10^2. The data is deleted as soon as it is entered. (I presume this lesson will be pretty engrained in your mind after you re-enter the data after formatting as text).